# Numeric solver (approximate decimal solution) in R

Tags: r, math, interpolation, solver

I'm try to geometrically interpolate population data using R.

I have a number for the year 2000 (call it P0) and a number for the years 2006-2010 (Call it PT). PT for 2006-2010 is an average of all five of those years. I want to interpolate numbers for 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, and 2010, and I want it to be a geometric series so that the resulting values add up to the desired total.

Mathematically we use

```
new value = P*exp(r*t)
```

to determine the value after t periods of geometric growth.
So if I let t be the number of years since 2000 then mathematically I can say

```
5*Pt = P0*exp(6*r) + P0*exp(7*r) + P0*exp(8*r) + P0*exp(9*r) + P0*exp(10*r)
```

Or, equivalently

```
5*Pt/P0 = exp(6r)+exp(7r)+exp(8r)+exp(9r)+exp(10r)
```

Solving for r then would allow me to calculate the geometrically interpolated values that I want.

I am having difficulty finding a way to do this in R. the functions solve() and fsolve() appear to prefer to work with matrix multiplication, and that's not whatt I'm doing.

I've looked at an optimization library (lbfgs), but using it to solve my problem looks to be an ugly hack at best.

Is there a good and simple way to do this in R?

Comment: analytical solutions to equations that involve sums of exponentials are generally difficult or impossible. You'll probably have to go with a brute-force minimization solution. You don't need an external package, the built-in `optim()` should work for this ...

Comment: I understand that an analytical solution is not going to be simple or easy. I really was looking for a way to approximate it. I was hoping that there was a simple R command to do it, and it looks like optim() is the closest I'm going to get. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the best solution here was the `uniroot()`
function.

The full code ended up being

```
xmin <- uniroot(f = function (x) (exp(6*x) + exp(7*x) + exp(8*x) + exp(9*x) + exp(10*x) - target), interval = c(-1,3), f.lower = 0, f.upper = 0)
```

and then to get the appropriate x value I use `xmin$root`.